# COUNTY WebService API lookup from valid street address

Tags: web-service, address, united-states, county

I am looking for a solid WebService API that will allow me to submit an http request with a pre-validated US Street/City?state/Zip Address and return COUNTY in xml or json about 200 times per work day.  I am aware that Google, MapQuest & Bing do this however the response will go into an internal database, my use does not fit into their free Terms Of Service and I can not afford their large fee for my very small business.  It looks like TigerWeb may do it?  Is the data good enough?  What might a request look like? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Geonames JSON response adminName2 > http://api.geonames.org/findNearestAddressJSON?formatted=true&lat=37.451&lng=-122.18&username=demo&style=full

Answer (score 3):

[YAddress API](http://www.yaddress.net) gives you county name, county FP code and many other data fields for an address.

Here is a sample response in JSON:

```
Address Line 1: 506 4TH AVE APT 1
Address Line 2: ASBURY PARK, NJ 07712-6086
Number: 506
Street Predirection:    
Street Name:    4TH
Street Suffix:  AVE
Street Postdirection:   
Secondary Abbreviation: APT
Secondary Number:   1
City:   ASBURY PARK
State:  NJ
ZIP:    07712
ZIP4:   6086
County: MONMOUTH
State FP:   34
County FP:  025
Census Tract:   8070.03
Census Block:   1015
Latitude:   40.223571
Longitude:  -74.005973
Geocoding Precision:    5
```

(Disclusure: I work for the company making YAddress.)